# Formula to extract values from pivot table

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a raw data report in Excel 2016 (solution for google sheets is also fine) that has hundreds of records, each record contains:product sku number, name, price, category, manufacturer, production number. Please check: [Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vmrArmtgIG2badePOur-7Jd6SzrprqBv3YuU0LxK1qE/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to extract the manufacturer of WO_2297000 extracted from the example table (same for SB_03957 and for all of the products in the table). Same with the production number. I already tried to make this using vlookup, but it doesn't seems to work.

Any advice on how to make this work?

Comment: Try GETPIVOTDATA(data_field,pivot_table,field,item,...)

Comment: Why does Vlookup not work?  GETPIVOTDATA is great if you know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all the data which contains a `keyword` (e.g. `WO_2297000`, `SB_03957` etc), you could try using this query which will return you the data from the table which contains `WO_2297000`.

If you want to use it with the other keywords, just replace `WO_2297000` with the one you desire. Same goes with the ranges - they need to be adjusted to the ones you have in your main sheet.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A2:S19,"SELECT * WHERE A CONTAINS 'WO_2297000'",0))
```

**Reference**

- [Google Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage);
- [ARRAYFORMULA Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:S; REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!A:A; "WO_2297000|SB_03957"))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:S; "where A matches 'WO_2297000|SB_03957'"; 1)
```